# making header with logo on the left and letters on the right

Tags: html, css, header

I am making a header for my forms that i want to be at the top of my forms. I want the logo to appear on the left side and the title and sub titles to come right next to it. Right now the logo appears but for some reason the title comes a little below the logo.

HTML:

```
<div class= different_header>
  <img src="css_images/seal2.png" />

    THE PRINCE GEORGE'S COUNTY GOVERNMENT</br>
    OFFICE OF ETHICS AND ACCOUNTABILITY

</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .different_header{
        display: block; 
    }
    .different_header {

        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to give the `<div>` the same `line-height` as the height of the actual image?

Comment: i can try that right meow

Answer (score 1):

Check my jsFiddle here:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8v5a8nw/)

gave the image a `float:left;`

Comment: nice i dont know why i didnt use the float method before....would you recommend padding the thing too bc it floats all the way to the left and i want it to be more to the middle

Comment: you can give the `.different_header` some `padding-left:;`